How do I creat a dot net project template when when used within VS 2022 creates the project under a specific directory structure under the solution?
I want to create a .NET project template when it is used within Visual Studio 2022 to create a solution and project at the same time.
My solution will be in the root folder.  I want the project to be created in the directory of src/Services under the root folder.
Is there something I need to put in the template.json file?
I created the the project template with a nuspec file at the solution file to create the template’s nuget package.
I want to be able to take this approach with multiple project types, ASP.NET, Console projects, Class libraries, etc.
How can I do this?
